# Visualizing APEs (aka AME) from the bife package

Tags: r, ggplot2, effects, logits

How do I get this  'summary.bifeAPEs' list str data into a dataframe so I can plot the effects? I can't seem to coerce it into a dataframe using the recommendations from list data examples in SO.

```
library(bife)
test <- iris%>% mutate(LengthDummy= if_else(Sepal.Length>5, "Long", "Short") %>% as_factor(.)) %>%  
                 bife(LengthDummy~ Sepal.Width+ Petal.Length+Petal.Width
                      | Species, data = ., "logit")
APEsIris <- summary(get_APEs(test))
str(APEsIris)
```

Comment: What do you want the plot to look like exactly?

Comment: https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/index.html This is what they usually look like but this bife is not supported by ggeffects 
or by https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggiraphExtra/vignettes/ggPredict.html.